# Android platform game level editor

Tags: android

I'm trying my hand at making a platform game and have been thinking about what I would use to design levels.

I was thinking of using a tile palette that would contain the graphic tiles and their properties. And a similar palette that would contain sprites.

This way I could drag and drop tiles/sprites onto a grid and specify property values. This could all be saved to some kind of file that would be read by the game.

Without getting too into the details, is this a sound overall strategy? Is there anything major that I'm forgetting? Or perhaps there's a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather open-ended question, but I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach. You might have to try a few things to find out what works for you.

When I make platform games I find it useful to be able to edit levels while I'm playing them, by adding in code to the game which allows me to select a graphic tile from a palette and paint it onto the screen. The behaviour is usually linked to the graphic for my games but you could paint behaviour as well. You then need code for your game to save levels as well as load them. Obviously, you would probably want to remove the editor before releasing the game.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much experience you have with game dev, but if you're thinking about making a tile-based platform game then your best bet is leveraging existing libraries/tools to avoid "re-inventing the wheel". I highly suggest looking into open source libraries/tools because you can modify them to your liking. I've had some good experience with [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) and [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) in which case both have [TMX](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) support which is a file format that can be used in conjunction with [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map editor. I personally like libgdx because it has javadoc and very actively developed, and also that it's a framework rather than engine which gives you more flexibility (although more coding in some aspects).